# How to send search result, when clicked, to the database react firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, crud

Sorry for the weak title, couldn't properly word it.

What I am trying to achieve is similar to calorie tracking apps: I want to search for food in the firestore database, show the results, then if clicked, print it on screen and if I am finished/content with the data, send it to the users database when clicked on a button.
The searching function works, but I simply cannot even start with the data sending part.

This is my firestore database:
[image: I want the data to go to the tracking subcollection, grouped by the day it was tracked]

Here is my track screen so far:

```
export default function Track() {

    const [food, setFood] = useState([]);
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

    const onSearch = (searchTerm) => {
        setValue(searchTerm);
        console.log("search",  searchTerm);
    }

    const loadFood = async () => {
       
        await getDocs(collection(db, "food"))
            .then((querySnapshot)=>{               
                const newData = querySnapshot.docs
                    .map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id:doc.id }));
                    setFood(newData);                
                console.log(food, newData);
            })
       
    }
    useEffect(() => {
      loadFood();

      }, []);
    return (
        <div className='cont'>
            <div>
                <div className='header'  style={styles.headerContainer}>
                    <h1 className='headerText'>
                        What did you eat today?
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div style={styles.searchContainer}>
                    <input type="text" 
                    value={value}  onChange={(event) => {
                        setValue(event.target.value);
                    }} />
                    <div className='list' style={styles.list}>
                        <ul>
                            {
                                food.filter(item => {
                                    const searchTerm = value.toString().toLowerCase();
                                    const name = item.name.toString().toLowerCase();

                                    return (searchTerm && name.startsWith(searchTerm) && name !== searchTerm);
                                }).slice(0, 15).map((item, i) => (
                                    <div key={i} style={styles.listItem} >
//LIST ONCLICK HERE

                                        <li onClick={() => {
                                        firebase.firestore().collection("tracking").add(item);
                                        console.log('clicked' + item.name)
                                        }}>{item.name}</li>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    ))
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So what I need help with is:

- editing my onclick function so that it sends the data to the correct place
- showing the clicked items in a list underneath.  For this maybe I could use an array or something and then map through it?